# Massive linker slow down after porting solution form Visual Studio 2010 to 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, build, linker

I am porting a large solution (100s of projects, tens of thousands source files) from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2015; C++, x64, win32/MFC, some CUDA, OpenGL, OpenMP, many thirdparty dependencies, boost etc.

The Release mode (optimization on etc) builds faster in 2015 than it did in 2010 - awesome. However, in Debug mode, about a third of projects are having an excessive link time increase; i.e. one project linked in 2010 in about 2 minutes, now takes 4 hours in 2015.

I ran with /VERBOSE mode, and diagnostics on; did not find any specific information why the linker is actually slow. Watching the link.exe process shows massive I/O (terabytes) for the troubled projects against one of the core libraries that we build and link against. Compilation and link flags are in line with what 2010 had.

I cannot wrap my head on what would be causing this. Any suggestions or sources on where to look at linker intricacies would be much appreciated. Or perhaps a better way to diagnose what the linker bottleneck.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered that it might simply be a VS regression and report it to MS?

Comment: ^ what Jesper says. 2 minutes to 4 hours isn't anywhere near normal, nor have I seen any other reports about such slowness so it seems you hit some edge case bug. Have to ask though: all antivirus etc disabled?

Comment: Yeah, all AV disabled, will try porting to 2017, see how that goes :) thanks!

Comment: How about porting to 2017? Maybe some settings of the linker have been changed. I suggest you can check if there are some changes in the linker option settings between VS2010 and VS2015. Such as enable incremental linking and make link status. Besides, have you try to clean the %temp% folder?